# Store the result of IfSubStr and then count with StrCount

Tags: xstring

I want to store the result of `IfSubStr` (from package `xstring`) for using it later.  So I define a command and I redefined with the result of `IfSubStr`.  So far, so good.  But now I want also to use `StrCount` on the result.  The folllowing error shows up:

```
Argument of \@xs@StrCount has an extra }
```

I think it is related to the expansion of the arguments, but I do not know much about it, so I was not able to solve the problem.  Any help?  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\XXX}{}
\newcommand{\DoSomethingWith}[1]{String is #1.}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\XXX}{\IfSubStr{AC}{A}{ax}{xbx}}  
    \DoSomethingWith{\XXX}

    \StrCount{ax}{x}\ x.

    \StrCount{\XXX}{x}\ x. % Error
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in a different way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\XXX}{}
\newcommand{\DoSomethingWith}[1]{String is #1.}
\begin{document}
\IfSubStr{AC}{A}{\renewcommand{\XXX}{ax}}{\renewcommand{\XXX}{xbx}}

\DoSomethingWith{\XXX}

\StrCount{ax}{x}\ x.

\StrCount{\XXX}{x}\ x. % Error
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does this work and the former does not?  Originally, I wrote what you suggest.  However, actually I have the concatenation of several `IfSubStr`.  This forced me to redefine several commands (one additional command for each `IfSubStr`), and then I switched from several `IfSubStr` containing one `renewcommand` each, to one `renewcommand` containing several `IfSubStr`.

Comment: @ASdeL It's the usual problem: `\IfSubStr` doesn't produce the string directly, but the instructions to produce it.